# Upload file to a common google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have a web app which allow users to upload files. I have created a google account specifically for my web app e.g mywebapp@gmail.com. I want every file that a user uploads from my web app to get saved to my web app's google drive. 
I am using the below method to upload a file to google drive and works perfectly fine. But the problem is the file gets saved to the google drive of the person itself if he has a google account. Where in the code can i say to upload file to mywebapp@gmail.com account?

```
function uploadFile(evt) {
        alert('Hello');
         gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
           insertFile();
         });
       }

       /**
        * Insert new file.
        */
       function insertFile() {
         const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846264';
         const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
         const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";
         var appState = {
           number: 12,
           text: 'hello'
         };
         var fileName = 'csusbdt-drive-example-app-state.txt';
         var contentType = 'application/json';
         var metadata = {
           'title': fileName,
           'mimeType': contentType
         };
         var base64Data = btoa(JSON.stringify(appState));
         var multipartRequestBody =
             delimiter +
             'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
             JSON.stringify(metadata) +
             delimiter +
             'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
             'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
             '\r\n' +
             base64Data +
             close_delim;
         var request = gapi.client.request({
             'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files',
             'method': 'POST',
             'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
             'headers': {
               'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
             },
             'body': multipartRequestBody});
         request.execute(function(arg) {
           console.log(arg);
         });
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

"Where in the code can i say to upload file to mywebapp@gmail.com account?"

It doesn't work like that. At some point in your code initialisation, you requested an Access Token. It's this Access Token that determines which Drive account is uploaded to. Pretty much all of the Google sample code shows how to obtain an Access Token for the current user's account, so I'm guessing you've copy pasted that.

What you need is an Access Token for your storage account. The best way to obtain one of these is by first obtaining a Refresh Token, which you store someplace safe on a server, and then create an endpoint to return an Access Token for the saves Refresh Token.

However...

You need to be very aware of the security implications of what you're trying to do. GDrive has very coarse grained permissions, which means that any user with an Access Token that allows inserts, is also allowed to delete or change existing content.

Because of the security concerns, I would suggest that you look at having a server GDrive proxy that handles the access to GDrive and only permits safe operations.

Comment: the last paragraph is the most important. you want server-side oauth flow, not client-side.